# How to convert a multi-dimensional array model to a tuple structure in CPLEX?

Tags: tuples, cplex

I would like to use a large dataset (3100 demand locations) for my facility location problem.

One of the constraints is the size of the distance matrix. If I use a 2d array for distance between locations, I store a very large amount of unnecessary data. (Like long distances which I will not use in my model, so I add another constraint like <= maxdist )

Instead of using a 2D array I am trying to use the following tuple, however if I don`t use the complete distance matrix (which converted to a tuple) I do not get a solution ?

Thanks for your suggestions ...

```
    {string} Supply = ...;      // Supply locations
    {string} DC = ...;          // Candidate facility locations
    {string} Demand = ...;      // Demand locations

    tuple Dist_Tup{
    string FROM;
    string TO;
    float MILES;
    };

    setof(Dist_Tup) DistanceTmp=...;
    setof(Dist_Tup) Distance = { <FROM,TO,MILES> | <FROM,TO,MILES> in DistanceTmp : FROM in Supply || FROM in DC};

    dexpr float TransportCost1 = sum(i in Supply , a in Alt , j in DC , p in Period, BB in Distance : BB.TO==j && BB.FROM==i) X[i][a][j][p]*Dist[BB]*C[i][j];

    //dexpr float TransportCost1 = sum(i in Supply , a in Alt , j in DC , p in Period) X[i][a][j][p]*G[i][a][j]*C[i][j];
```

Comment: Does it work with small example problems, e.g. with 3, 4 or 5 locations to check the logic and consistency

Comment: The tuple structure is not working with small sizes, but I used the array structure (line with //dexpr...) for small problems which works fine...

Comment: The model should be similar or the same from both implementations. I suggest you try a small instance with both versions and export the model from CPLEX as LP files so that you can compare them.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick thank you for your comments, but my main problem is on the tuple coding itself not the results. I am able to run the code with tuple structure, I would be glad if you could check the codes...

Comment: If you export the LP file from both versions of the code using a small dataset, you should be able to see the differences in the two models and that should give you a big clue where your implementation using the tuples is wrong. Exporting the LP file is easy and doesn't need the model to be solveable.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick thanks for the tip I have used LP files for both and finally I solved my problem. I uploaded the solution under my answer (just in case someone needs it)

Comment: Thanks - its *VERY* useful to be able to use the exported LP files to check your model. You can also manually add constraints into the generated LP files and re-solve to restrict or fix variable values which can also help diagnose issues. Hope you enjoy this stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> My new Code as a solution :
>
> ```
> tuple Arc { 
>  string FROM;
>  string TO;
> } 
> tuple Dist_Tup{
>  string FROM;
>  string TO;
>  float MILES;
> };
> setof(Dist_Tup) Distance=...;
> setof(Arc) SDC_Arcs = { <FROM,TO> | <FROM,TO,MILES> in Distance : FROM in Supply && TO in DC};
> setof(Arc) SD_Arcs =  { <FROM,TO> | <FROM,TO,MILES> in Distance : FROM in Supply && TO in Demand && MILES<=maxDist};
> setof(Arc) DCD_Arcs = { <FROM,TO> | <FROM,TO,MILES> in Distance : FROM in DC && TO in Demand && MILES<=maxDist};
>
> dexpr float TransportCost1 = sum(i in Supply , a in Alt , j in DC , p in Period, DIST in Distance : DIST.FROM==i && DIST.TO==j, ARC in SDC_Arcs : ARC.FROM==i && ARC.TO==j) X[ARC][a][p]*G2[DIST]*C[i][j];
> ```